# SSRS - Make Allow NULL shared dataset parameter not required in report parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a shared dataset that calls a stored procedure with optional parameters (they are defaulted to NULL).  I have set them to "Allow NULL" in the shared dataset.  Is there a way to set up the report that uses this shared dataset so I don't have to add every parameter to the parameter list?  It seem redundant to have to add every one then hide and set to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You mean report parameters, not query parameters, right? Report parameters belong to the report, not the dataset. You best option would be a template based approach.

1. Create a Report Project Template for Visual Studio that includes the parameters.
2. Utilize the Reporting Service api within an internal tool and pull down the definition of a known (base) report and create a new .rdl file locally and include it in your project.
3. Tried and true copy and paste from a bare bones report that includes your dataset link and parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I created a template, but the problem comes when, say, I have to change or add a parameter to the shared dataset (and underlying SP).  I then have to update every report that uses that dataset, regardless if it's actually needed on every report.  Just trying to see if I could use that dataset and only add the parameters needed on that particular report and, in theory, treat the non-existent ones like getting NULL values.

Comment: You would still have to add the parameters to the report to be mapped to the dataset, right?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid :)  Feels like it should be possible!

Comment: I don't think this will auto-magically occur within VS or in the uploaded reports linked to the dataset. You might have to go out of your way for this one :/

Comment: If you add a parameter to the stored procedure.. then every report that uses that SP will complain about not providing a value for the parameter.. sorry.. that's how SSRS rolls.. unfortunately.